# GWT upgrading from 2.5RC to 2.5 - NoClassDefFoundError HtmlTemplates?

Tags: gwt, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, gwt-2.5

I just wondered how to fix my project to avoid this error after I moved my project to a new computer from a 2.5RC setup to a 2.5 setup. It was working before. Of course `HtmlTemplates` may not exist in the 2.5 client-side library, but I'm not bothered about that, I just want my UI to show:

```
11:24:08.060 [ERROR] [myapp] Failed to create an instance of 'org.myapp.client.UI' via deferred binding 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'org.myapp.client.UIDesktop$Binder' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)

...

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/model/HtmlTemplates
at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderWriter.&lt;init&gt;(UiBinderWriter.java:181)
at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generateOnce(UiBinderGenerator.java:188)

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.model.HtmlTemplates
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have just the 2.5 .jars (not 2.5RC), and .classpath seems to be all pointing to them, I've tried clearing the gwt-Cache, the generated .js file, running "Clean Project" all to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There indeed is no such class in 2.5, but it was removed long before the first 2.5 RC. It only existed in 2.3 and 2.4.

Double-check your classpath, you must be referencing some 2.4 or 2.3 gwt-user.jar. Either that or you're using some third-party library that shadows some UiBinder classes with their own implementations, based on GWT 2.4 or 2.3 (IIRC, GWT-Platform does such a thing for its `GinUiBinder`); it might then have manifest during your 2.5RC to 2.5 upgrade because you changed the dependency order in your classpath and pushed gwt-user after the third-party lib.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! It seems to have been Errai. Downloading the latest version of Errai appears to have been what has fixed it, although the dependency order thing makes sense too, so it might be just that.